# While Loop in Bash Unexpected Character

Tags: bash, while-loop, grep, do-while

So I'm writing a script that will take the output of a grep as an array and then iterate a filter over it to output to a file. I'm testing it on my own site and the wget works as expected and generates a list of URLS in the spider.queue. The grep command will also work in terms of filtering by a keyword, but when I add it into a while loop and use an if statement to check if it already exists I'll get the error;

./spider.sh: 19: ./spider.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "done")

Which would lead me to believe it's a syntax problem with one of the loops.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Usage - ./spider.sh searchterm www.website.com

## Parameters

search=$1
URL=$2

## Spider WGET

wget -r -e robots=off --header="Accept: text/html" --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0" http://$URL 2>&1 | grep '^--' 2>&1 | awk '{ print $3 }' | grep -v '\.\(css\|js\|png\|gif\|jpg\|JPG\)$' >> spider.queue

## Keyword filter with grep

while true
 do
    PROFILES=($(grep -l -r "$search" $URL))
    for x in ${PROFILES[*]}
    do
            if grep -q $x crawler.queue; then
                    echo "Already Exists"
            else
                    $x >> crawler.queue
            fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Do you mean `echo "$x" >> crawler.queue` ?

Comment: You're right I should have that in, missed that thank you. Unfortunately I still get the same error on line 19

Comment: Try quoting all your variables, e.g. `wget ... "http://$URL"` and `grep -q "$x" crawler.queue`

Comment: Is the code above simplified? Your `while true` will run for ever. Perhaps there was something wrong with the string that you replaced with `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/bin/sh` does not support arrays, so the syntax error is caused by `PROFILES=(...`.

Switch to `#!/bin/bash`.