# Unexpected characters coming in bash in while loop

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am trying to get IP of a few 1000 domains...
below is my program...

```
#!/bin/bash
yesterday=$(date --date "1 days ago" +%F)

while read -r line comment
do
  
    ip=$(host -4 $line | head -1 | awk -F" " '{print $5}')
  
    echo "$ip"

done <  /home/domainsa/public_html/data/domains/$yesterday-domains.txt
```

it shows me

sh -x domains-ip.sh

```
++ date --date '1 days ago' +%F
+ yesterday=2021-05-02
+ read -r line comment
++ host -4 $'0-96.com\r'
++ head -1
++ awk '-F ' '{print $5}'
+ ip='3(NXDOMAIN)'
+ echo '3(NXDOMAIN)'
3(NXDOMAIN)
+ read -r line comment
++ host -4 $'0-roll.com\r'
++ head -1
++ awk '-F ' '{print $5}'
+ ip='3(NXDOMAIN)'
+ echo '3(NXDOMAIN)'
3(NXDOMAIN)
+ read -r line comment
++ host -4 $'000850.xyz\r'
++ head -1
++ awk '-F ' '{print $5}'
+ ip='3(NXDOMAIN)'
+ echo '3(NXDOMAIN)'
3(NXDOMAIN)
+ read -r line comment
++ host -4 $'00097971.com\r'
++ head -1
++ awk '-F ' '{print $5}'
+ ip='3(NXDOMAIN)'
+ echo '3(NXDOMAIN)'
3(NXDOMAIN)
```

$ and ' and \r is not something I was expecting...

Any idea where I am doing wrong?

I check [While Loop in Bash Unexpected Character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558952/while-loop-in-bash-unexpected-character)
but the selected answer I am also using...

PS: is there any better and quick bash command line I am missing to get IP address of domains...  This is all I know, so wrote this program.

[EDIT]

I am using `awk -F" " '{print $4}`

Comment: If you don't want to have the carriage return characters in the input, pipe it through `dos2unix`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file `...domains.txt` contains carriage returns (`\r`). These non-printable characters are shown by bash by using C-style strings (`$'someString'`) so that the non-printable carriage is visible.

You probably have windows line endings (`\r\n`) instead of linux line endings (`\n`). You could convert the file by using `dos2unix`. But just to be sure, you can remove all `\r` in the file with `tr -d \\r < ...dommains.txt`.

```
#!/bin/bash
yesterday=$(date --date "1 days ago" +%F)
tr -d \\r < "/home/domainsa/public_html/data/$yesterday-domains.txt" |
while read -r line comment
do
    host -4 "$line" | head -n1 | awk -F' ' '{print $5}'
done
```

Comment: If you echoed inside the loop, then that output would have been filtered by `awk` too. I moved the `awk` inside the loop again. Please try again. If that still doesn't work, please edit your answer so that I can see where exactly you want to echo.

Comment: Always single-quote strings in shell unless you **need** to double-quote or unquote them. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes. Not following that rule is what's causing you to need double escapes in the `tr` argument. It should be `tr -d '\r'`, not `tr -d \\r`. Having said that, that will remove all `\r`s instead of just the ones at the end of each line (unlike `dos2unix` or `sed 's/\r$//'`, for example) which may not be desirable (but is probably OK given the OPs sample input).

Comment: @EdMorton I'm aware of bash's different quoting mechanism. Can you explain what exactly `'\r'` should do better than `\\r` except for sticking to your credo of always using single-quotes if possible? To me, `\\r` looks more readable than `'\r'` and is also shorter and easier to type. Also, as I already wrote in my answer, I used `tr` specifically to delete *all* `\r` (not only those at the end of the line) from what OP wrote it is possible that the file contains `\r`s in the middle of each lines to separate the url from the comment.

Comment: That's like asking what `x=7; echo $x` will do better than `x=7; echo "$x"` or what `echo '7' | read line` will do better than `echo '7' | read -r line`. It's not that removing the quotes and adding a backslash won't produce the same result, it's that quoting is something that everyone should always do by default and removing the quotes is something you do when you have to, not the other way around, and so that should be what we show in answers so newcomers reading them learn the right "credo" and don't end up getting surprised (e.g. when they don't quote a string) in other situations.

Comment: No, the difference between `$x` and `"$x"` is immense, whereas `\\r` and `'\r'` are equivalent. Because I am aware of how bash works I often write `echo word` instead of `echo 'word'` and `\\r` instead of `'\r'`. To me, *"always use quotes"* feels like *"always use constants instead of "magic" numbers"* which may end up in something unnecessary like `one=1; i=i+one`. *"always"* is the problem. In your first comment it seemed like you called me out for doing something "wrong" when everything was fine. But maybe I misunderstood you and you just wanted to give a general quoting lesson to newbies.

Comment: It's mostly for the benefit of people reading your answer in future. `$x` and `"$x"` are equivalent when `x` is `7` as I said in my comment. `\\r` is equivalent to `'\r'` but `\\r<blank><blank>$x` is not equivalent to `'\r<blank><blank>$x'` while `\\r\<blank>\<blank>\$x` is. So, is the best approach to keep escaping every char that needs to be escaped or just quote the string?

Comment: Given that quoting the string is obviously simpler and less error-prone for a longer string, there's no reason to special-case a shorter string and escape the chars to possibly save a character vs simply quoting the string correctly and if you simply always do that then you never end up getting bit by a case where you didn't do it because you thought you didn't have to.